# What does it mean for the connections of this transformer to be in parallel?

Tags: transformer

Using [this transformer](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Coilcraft/HA4061-AL?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduik%2FctKpTJn54avFL%2FF4plAAbk6PTGuB38%3D), [datasheet.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/597/ha4061-463522.pdf)

When the datasheet indicates that the windings are connected in parallel, is it referring to connecting pin 1 with 2, 11 with 12, 8 with 7, and 6 with 5?

If yes, what is the reason this flyback transformer is manufactured in this manner, rather than connecting the respective pins within the transformer?

Comment: The datasheet is does not say much. My guess would be it leaves open the possibility of isolated outputs, and the possibility of putting them in series. Note that since it is running at high frequency, having multiple thinner wire is preferable to single thicker wire. So they most likely are also of same length and parallel wound to match inductance. Using single windings would halve the available current (for the same heat dissipation).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they want you to connect the pins as you say. They probably do it for a few reasons:

- It's how they built and tested it
- It might make it a bit more reliable
- It might make it a bit more efficient
- It might be easier to manufacture this way
- It may be this part is easily adapted for use at either 120V or 230V